# Finding a length (x) inside a circle sector given another length (y) and the arc length (s)

Tags: geometry, circles

I am stuck on a problem and can not seem to find a solution, maybe someone here can help me or at least tell me if it is possible to solve?

Please look at the figure:

[image: figure]

The problem is: Find the length $x$ given the length $y$ and the arc length $s$. The circle sector angle is unknown but less than 90 degrees.

Comment: The solution involves $\operatorname{sinc}^{-1}$ which has [no simple closed form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194652/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-sinc).

Comment: I suspected something like that, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the section angle is $\theta$ and radius is $r$, then we have

\begin{align}
s &= r\theta, \tag1 \\ 
y &= r\sin\theta, \tag2 \\
x &= r - r\cos\theta. \tag3
\end{align}

Using (2)/(1) we find that 
\begin{gather}
\frac{\sin\theta}\theta=\frac ys \iff \theta = \operatorname{sinc}^{-1}\frac ys. \\
r =\frac y{\sin\theta} = \frac y{\sin(\operatorname{sinc}^{-1}\frac ys)}
\end{gather}
Thus
$$ x = r(1-\cos\theta) = \frac{y\left(1-\cos\theta\right)}{\sin\theta} = y\tan\frac\theta2=y\tan\left(\frac12\operatorname{sinc}^{-1}\frac ys\right). $$

There is [no simple inverse of the sinc function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194652/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-sinc), so we cannot simplify further.

Answer (score 0):

First let there be an arbitrary radius r.

By the arc length formula, $$r\theta=s$$

Now consider the pythagorean theorem.

$$r^2=y^2+(r-x)^2$$
$$0=y^2-2rx+x^2.$$
$$2rx=y^2+x^2$$
$$r=(y^2+x^2)/2x$$

Therefore
$$s=\theta(y^2+x^2)/2x$$
$$2xs/(y^2+x^2)=\theta$$
Now
$$sin(2xs/(y^2+x^2))/y=sin(\pi/2)/r$$ 
$$sin(2xs/(y^2+x^2))=2xy/(x^2+y^2)$$
But
$$cos(2xs/(y^2+x^2))=(r-x)/r=1-2x^2/(x^2+y^2)$$
so, by the sin^2+cos^2=1 identity, 
$$1-4x^2/(x^2+y^2)+4x^4/(x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4)+4x^2y^2/(x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4)=1$$
Simplifying, this is actually just a true statement. The closest we can get to a solution is thus the previous finding:
$$sin(2xs/(y^2+x^2))=2xy/(x^2+y^2)$$
This can be used to solve s in terms of x and y, but you need infinite series to solve for x in terms of y and s.